# Do these mean the same: "your friends, boss" .vs. "your friends, your boss"?

Tags: grammar

Do these have the same meaning? And are they both grammatically correct?

> your friends, your lover, your boss, your dog.
>
> your friends, lover, boss, dog.

I don't want to put "your" after every comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are. The difference would be what is emphasized, the second is just a list, the first stresses that these things are *really* *yours*.  You might do that if you were in an argument about the ownership of the items, but it's not typical.

Comment: Thank you! So the second one is more common and natural? I will use it in my app slogan. I think I should use the second one, right?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, noarm. Yes, variations would most likely be rendered as "your friends, lover, boss, and dog." (Or some would write, "... boss and dog" (no final common).) You can also make it a bit humorous sounding by: "your friends, lover, boss, and your dog."  If you like my answer, please up vote it (the up arrow to the left) and, if you think it's the best answer, you can click the check box for 'accepting' the answer, as well. That's how it's done here. (You can also wait to see if you get more answers too, of course.) it's up to you :))

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) I can't vote up due to my low rep.

Comment: You're welcome --- ok, I guess I forgot about that limitation. Well, if you post questions and give answers, your rep. will increase reasonably quickly!

Comment: You might also put the word 'your' in before each if the text was likely to be heard rather than read. "Your friends, lovers, boss, dog" would *sound* very similar to "Your friend's lover's boss' dog", but means something completely different.